# Estimate of the sample proportion with

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

If I have a company with 1000 employees and 20% are female, and I want to select 20 of them at random, can I say that there is 95% certainty that the number of female employees in the sample will be between X and Y, where X is 4+1.96*sqrt(0.2*(0.8)/20)*20 and Y is 4-1.96*sqrt(0.2*(0.8)/20)*20, so 0.5 to 7.5, or 1 to 8 after rounding? In other words, would between 1 and 8 employees be female in 95% of the 20 employee samples I pick at random?

Comment: You can use math markup here, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated/1605#1605.  Please do!